# Lisp associative list

Tags: lisp, associative

```
(defun next ()
  (defparameter *sentences*
    '(
      (1 . "Test 1")
      (2 . "Test 2")))

  (let (sentence '(assoc 2 *sentences*)) ;This quote is needed, another program evaluates this.
    (format t "*sentences*:~%~a~%sentence: ~a~%" *sentences* sentence)))
```

It gives output
"*sentences*:
((1 . Test 1) (2 . Test 2))
sentence: NIL".

Why doesn't it give (2 . Test 2) as the value of "sentence"?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: added parentheses. The original program has matched parentheses.

Comment: A `DEFPARAMETER` inside a `DEFUN` is almost always wrong.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Then where should I put this?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: @RainerJoswig Initialize the variable \*sentences\* when the function is called. It can be the case that it is only initialized once, so subsequent function calls don't initialize it again.

Comment: Use `DEFPARAMETER` to define/initialize **global** special variables. Use `SETF` or `SETQ` to set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing parentheses in your `let` form:

```
(defun next ()
  (defparameter *sentences*
    '(
      (1 . "Test 1")
      (2 . "Test 2")))
  (let ((sentence (assoc 2 *sentences*))) ;no quote, just parentheses ;-)
    (format t "*sentences*:~%~a~%sentence: ~a~%" *sentences* sentence)))
```